# Path Of SVG Image Uploaded By user in WebSite

Tags: javascript, svg

I build this pen  , and it is work on my path image  .

```js
   //Circle

$(document).on('click','#Change_Green_Circle',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
  var img = document.getElementById('imgCircle');
  
   img.style.fill = 'Green';

});
    

$(document).on('click','#Change_Yellow_Circle',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
  var img = document.getElementById('imgCircle');
  
   img.style.fill = 'Yellow';

});

// Wiki

$(document).on('click','#Change_Green_wiki',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
  var img = document.getElementById('imgWiki');
  
   img.style.fill = 'Green';

});
    

$(document).on('click','#Change_Yellow_wiki',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
  var img = document.getElementById('imgWiki');
  
   img.style.fill = 'Yellow';

});


//Rest


$(document).on('click','#Rest',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      
  var circle = document.getElementById('imgCircle');
  
   var wiki = document.getElementById('imgWiki');
  
    imgWiki.style.fill = 'Red';
    imgCircle.style.fill = 'Black';


});
```

```css
  @import "compass/css3";


.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 164px;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg  id="imgCircle" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
   xml:space="preserve" class="logo">

<ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
  
<path id="imgWiki" style="fill: red" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
<filter id="pictureFilter" >
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
</filter>
</svg>

<button type="button" id="Change_Green_Circle">Change Circle to Green</text>

<button type="button" id="Change_Yellow_Circle">Change Circle to Yellow</text>
 
  
<button type="button" id="Change_Green_wiki">Change wiki to Green</text>

<button type="button" id="Change_Yellow_wiki">Change Wiki to Yellow</text>
  
  <button type="button" id="Rest">Rest </text>
```

BUT

I want to allow the user to upload SVG in my site, and to do the same function i did in my pen above, so I need to take the path of  image uploaded by the user , HOW ?

> 1- which programming language i need to use ?
>
> 2- how to take the path
>    of the uploaded SVg image by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/recouwnh/19/

**What does fiddle do**:
01) Retrieve details of dragged SVG image by user.
02) Then convert that image data into SVG tags, with appropriate tags like circle, path etc.
03) On click of "Change Color" button, script finds all path elements from viewing SVG and give them random colors.

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="viewer">
    <label class="viewer-switch">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="alert-error"></div>
    <div class="introbox"></div>
    <div class="viewer-wrap"></div>
    <a style="display: none;"></a>
  <p>Drop your content here</p>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" name="btn_changecolor" id="btn_changecolor">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

**JS Code**:

```
var viewerCtrl = new ViewerController(document.querySelector('.viewer'));
// Cheap way to inform the user about errors.
var alertBoxTimeout, alertBox = document.querySelector('.alert-error');
window.onerror = function (msg) {
    alertBox.textContent = msg;
    alertBox.classList.add('show');
    if (!alertBoxTimeout) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alertBox.classList.remove('show');
        }, 8000);
    }
};

$('#btn_changecolor').on('click', function(){
    var min=0, max=255, random1 = 0, random2 = 0, random3 = 0;
    $('.viewer-wrap svg path').each(function(){
        random1 = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min; 
        random2 = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min; 
        random3 = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min; 
        this.style.fill = 'rgb('+ random1 +', '+ random2 +', '+ random3 +')';
    });
});
```

Taken reference from
01) https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/ (SVG Animation Playground)
02) Original github link which created above SVG animation:
 https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus
03) https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/scripts/ViewerCtrl.js (Used to create draggable area & prepare SVG from the data which is getting read from user uploading image)

**Note**: Have checked working of this fiddle with SVG only. For changing the colors of specific path elements, you need to find out your own way.

Hope this will be useful too you.

Comment: you are genius sir